# Cannot assign value of type 'pantalla9' to type 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource?'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a page view in the view controller.

I am unable to assign value of type 'pantalla9' to type 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource?'

Here is the Error message:

[image]

Here is the next error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement

> UIPageViewControllerDataSource

in your ViewController

Comment: now appears an error in: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1 signal SIGABRT)

Comment: Share me the screenshot.

Comment: I have put into question. Next error.

Comment: Your application is crashing. Can u share me the whole codebase?

Comment: It took me a lot to do and I can not put it in this post.

Comment: What part do you need to see?

Comment: I am trying to maintain reputation in stackoverflow, but I do not know what is poorly written up in this question in order to fix.